# how to share tensorflow model in different celery task workers

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, celery

I am doing some NLP work and there are models trained by Tensorflow. I provide some APIs to accomplish word cut using these models and dispatching the requests through Celery.

The case is:

**Celery will dispatch tasks to different workers(about 4-5) therefore each worker has to load the models above and consequently the Memory will be occupied a lot.**

**So any ways to share the models among the workers?** I do not actually know about the underlying mechanism of Celery worker.

Thanks

Comment: You could have a look at [Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) which serves your model as a gRPC API. It supports [batching](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/batching/README.md) which sounds like what you are trying to do. If you really need celery for some reason (eg running these tasks in the background) you can just call the Tensorflow Serving API from celery tasks.

Comment: @geniass Thanks for your answer!!Actually, i am to consider about using Tensorflow Serving for models deployment in the future. The asynchronous celery tasks are used at the client, so I create a **singleton** class and a function in it loading the models at the server to ensure these models could only be loaded once. It works, but i am not sure the solution is good enough. i will try tf serving to determine the performance. Thanks again.

Comment: Ya I have been doing the same thing to serve torch models, but since this doesn't support batching automatically I am pretty sure you'll be able to get much better performance with TF serving. I'll make my comment an answer so you can close this question.

Comment: @aforwardz did you end up setting up one server for tensorflow serving, and for celery workers to call to do inference? I am trying to glue existing infrastructure (celery) with tensorflow serving, since to me, with TF serving, we can avoid deciding the trade off between model pre-loading (high memory usage) or loading and destroying the model for handling multiple models in each celery worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) which serves your model as a gRPC API. It supports [batching](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/batching/README.md) which sounds like what you are trying to do. If you really need celery for some reason (eg running these tasks in the background) you can just call the Tensorflow Serving API from celery tasks.

Comment: I am trying to deploy my model into tf serving. I look through the document and it seemingly have already accomplished something that I want. Thanks bro.